# I am trying to make a merge conflict happen. I get the opposite and terminal says a recursive strategy is used

Tags: git, merge, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

I am doing an assignment and it calls to do a git merge after changing two `< headings >` (in my `index.html`) on across two different branches.

I've tried doing it. After changing the headings to a different word (or adding an additional word), I then made sure that `HEAD` is pointing to the previous but most recent commit on the `git log` results by doing:

1. the command `git checkout [previous commit sha]`
2. seeing that `HEAD` is in a *detached state*

   then
3. switching back to the `master` branch (the assignment calls to do that)

I run `git merge` since on `master` branch and I get the output/result

> merge made by 'recursive' strategy

What am I doing wrong?

[image: my terminal]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've [edit]ed your question a bit, to make it better readable to people who can potentially answer it.

Comment: It sounds like you're deliberately trying to create a conflict (to see how it works?) ... and you simply failed to create a conflict "severe" enough that it couldn't be corrected automatically.  SUGGESTION: look [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) for more details.

Comment: What ended up in the file?

Comment: If you want to generate a conflict which cannot be resolved by git automatically, you have the modify on both branches the same file at the same line or so (1 or 2 lines before or after). Then you'll have a conflict and can resolve it.

Comment: What's the output of the command `git log --oneline --all index.html`?

Answer (score -1):

> Recursive is the current default two-head strategy, but after some
>   searching I finally found some info about the "resolve" merge
>   strategy.
>
> This can only resolve two heads using a 3-way merge algorithm. When
>   there is more than one common ancestor that can be used for 3-way
>   merge, it creates a merged tree of the common ancestors and uses that
>   as the reference tree for the 3-way merge. This has been reported to
>   result in fewer merge conflicts without causing mismerges by tests
>   done on actual merge commits taken from Linux 2.6 kernel development
>   history. Additionally this can detect and handle merges involving
>   renames, but currently cannot make use of detected copies. This is the
>   default merge strategy when pulling or merging one branch.

Comment: How is this relevant?